# Seeking Shulhan Aruch Hamidot

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books

If anyone has information on how I can purchase the Sefer "Shulhan Aruch HaMidot" it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.otzar.org/wotzar/book.aspx?161674

This link should help you.

Comment: That's an online one, but thanks anyway.